# How to understand KnowkOutJs in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, knockout

- How to understand KnockOut Js in Magento 2 ?
- I am working in Checkout and cart page, I debugged a lot but i am not
  able to understand any single line code of KnockOut Js
- But without Magento 2, I am able to understand KnockOut Js.

**Can anyone please guide me about How to understand or debug KnockOut Js in Magento 2.**

Comment: You can check this link for understand KnockOut Js with example. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/knockoutjs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer following link and videos using these you can get basic idea of how to use knockout js and also require js in magento 2.

https://www.mage2.tv/content/javascript/